# Getting PXE-E78 error when trying to network boot

Tags: networking, images, pxe-boot

When imaging a laptop or desktop through our network, I keep getting these errors. The fix I've found is starting Windows up before I throw up our company image and doing a renew/refresh in cmd. Any ideas as to What could be the root of the problem?

Comment: You haven't given us much to work with.  PXE-E78 means that the boot server could not be found, it sounds like the machine can't contact the boot server.  More details about your setup will be needed if we're going to be able to help.

Comment: Well, it's not consistently happening if that helps.  I will throw up a batch of 10 or so devices and one or two of them will run into the issue. The rest work just fine. We are using Desktop and Server Mgmt from Front Range Solutions in order to push our applications and OS to the devices. What sort of info would help?